# Azure Graph, filtering on activity and group membership

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

Is it possible, within a single GET call, to only obtain users who are members of one group, not a member of a different group and have signed in within X days?

I have been trying to do this with a call similar to:-

"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=id,signInActivity&$expand=memberOf&$filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2021-04-26T17:30:09Z&$filter=contains(memberOf.id,'11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111') and NOT contains(memberOf,'222222-2222-2222-2222-22222222')&$top=999"

but however I try to formulate the filter parameters it always produces an error

Comment: Hi @RahulKumarShaw-MT, the suggested solution, which would be very useful, does not appear to work. I suspect that the signInActivity resource is only available under the /users/ path and not under the /groups/ path. I have added comments below to your suggested solution

Comment: Hello @Bramha, Checking from my side as well for the possibilties to apply filter at group level. Will update the answer once done.

Comment: Hello @Bramah, You were correct signInActivity resource is only available under the /users/ path and not under the /groups/ path. Update the answer Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below `MS GraphAPI` to get the list of members of particular group who has signed in under particular date and time.

> **Note : Details for the signInActivity property require an Azure AD
> Premium P1/P2 license and the AuditLog.Read.All permission**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{groupObjectID}?$expand=members&$filters=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime ge 2022-01-21T00:00:00Z&$select=id,displayName
```

[image]

[image]

***Note: The Microsoft Graph API only supports the resource type signInActivity in users end-point not in group end-point. This is reason we can not filter member based on LastSignInDateTime on a group level***

***For more information you can refer this [Document](https://morgantechspace.com/2021/09/find-last-login-date-for-all-azure-ad-users-using-powershell.html#report)***

Comment: This doesn't appear to filter the users in any way based on the LastSignInDateTime. Changing the condition to "ge" or "le", changing the API to "beta" or "v1.0", I always receive the same results. (All of the users within the group have P2 licenses and the App has the AuditLog.Read.All permission granted).

Comment: Hello @Bramah, Updated the answer Please chek.

Comment: I have tried your new URL (thanks for that) but unfortunately still no joy. I still see exactly the same results when I use "ge" as when I use "le", which seems to me that this filter is not being applied as expected. I presume if it is applying the filter, this is being applied to the actual group and not the members :(

Comment: Add **ConsistencyLevel : Eventual** in Reuqest Header and then try again and also the select will be only perform on group level not the user level, but the filter is applied and i have verified using the users filter API as well.

Comment: No change unfortunately, I still see the same list of users being returned whether using "ge" or "le" :(

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw I just found out the query has `$filters` condition but it should be `$filter`, after that you would see "Request_UnsupportedQuery" error for the group api but the user api would work
```https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime ge 2022-03-18T00:00:00Z&$select=id,displayName,signInActivity```